# Display a python output with special characters in GUI label unity

Tags: c#, python-3.x, unity-game-engine, utf-8, special-characters

Am running a python script from unity, and I want the output to be displayed in a GUI label in unity, the output contain special characters like é,ç,... but am getting symbols instead.
This is what I tried so far but no luck

```
using (Process proc = Process.Start (start)) {
            using (StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput) {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding ();
                byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes (result);
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log (result);
                Message1.text = result; 
            }
        }
```

result is the output: it should be

```
('fromaje', 'Fausse:')
('Correction suggérér:','fromage')
```

But am getting:

[image]

Comment: I think we should at first try to figure out where the problem is occurring. Could you try logging a utf8 string and see if it will be printed correctly? And are you sure that the python script is printing valid utf8 to output?

Comment: Which unity version you are using? it does support this kind of character.

Comment: this sound like a basic conversion problem : byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); //display myString

Answer (score 1):

When you create your process use:

```
    var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "python.exe whatever.py",
        Arguments = "yourargs",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
 };
```

Then read the string by doing this:

```
proc.Start();
StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    bldr.append(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()+"\n");
}
```

You can get the full output by doing:

```
bldr.ToString()
```